# Create POJO Class for Kotlin

Tags: java, android, gson, kotlin, pojo

I want to create POJO class for Kotlin, as we know that [www.jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org) converts JSON to POJO so we can use it with gson.

Anyone know how to create Gson POJO for Kotlin **QUICKLY?**

**Edited:**

I know its use Data classes, but is there any simplest way to create it?

Comment: In Kotlin you write [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) instead of POJOs.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio I think you can create Java classes and then convert it to Kotlin.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, I got solution

for Example:

```
{
    "foo": "string",
    "bar": "integer",
    "baz": "boolean"
}
```

My POJO Class Created using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

#### Example.java

```
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("foo")
    @Expose
    private String foo;
    @SerializedName("bar")
    @Expose
    private String bar;
    @SerializedName("baz")
    @Expose
    private String baz;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String getBaz() {
        return baz;
    }

    public void setBaz(String baz) {
        this.baz = baz;
    }
}
```

Converted **Kotlin** Class using **`Code -> Convert Java File to Kotlin File`** or <kbd>CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + K</kbd>

#### Example.kt

```
class Example {

    @SerializedName("foo")
    @Expose
    var foo: String? = null
    @SerializedName("bar")
    @Expose
    var bar: String? = null
    @SerializedName("baz")
    @Expose
    var baz: String? = null
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: You did exactly what i described in my answer but i received negative votes instead ^^

Comment: you can use http://www.json2kotlin.com to generate kotlin data classes directly from json instead of needing a java conversion in between.

Comment: What about getter and setter in the kotlin case? And cant the variables be private? Please add a note on how to access those variable ( say bar)

Answer (score 77):

I think this should be the Plugin what you want

[image: JSON To Kotlin Class Plugin]

https://github.com/wuseal/JsonToKotlinClass

Comment: Update: Great plugin,But the studio gets stuck after the conversion(android studio version 2.3.3)

Comment: @Amalp Is that occurs every time ,I have just test ,everything goes well,can you paste your JsonString here?Or you can raise an detail issue here,https://github.com/wuseal/JsonToKotlinClass/issues       Thanks

Comment: @Amalp Thanks for your issue,new released version has fixed this problem,you can try with the new version

Answer (score 10):

A feature request about Kotlin support to auto generate data classes have been filled [here](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/593) in jsonschema2pojo github repository.
Currently, there is no jsonschema2kotlin web utility available.

If you don't have any problem installing a new plugin on Android Studio, follow the accepted answer, otherwise the best you can do is to use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to convert JSON to Java POJO and the use the Android Studio 3.0+ feature that converts a Java file to a Kotlin one.

[image]

Comment: Negative votes without explanations, nice job guys ;)

Comment: maybe they are afraid of [revenge downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106704/218381).

Answer (score 10):

```
data class ModelUser(val imagePath: String,val userName: String)
```

Unbelievable Right! Its as simple as that. Just use `data` keyword before `class` to create Data class in Kotlin.

Data class provides you with everything, getters, setters, hashCode, toString and equals functions. So all you have to do is create an instance and start using the functions.

Comment: A data class do not have a default constructor.

Comment: Certain JSON converters require classes to be constructible, but the previous comment is actually correct: one can use data classes with default parameters

Answer (score 6):

In vs-code there is a plugin named Paste JSON as Code.
it supports many languages.
[Paste Json as code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quicktype.quicktype)

[image: quick look]

Answer (score 5):

If I got your question, you might be searching some plugin for converting to POJO. So 
[RoboPOJOGenerator](https://github.com/robohorse/RoboPOJOGenerator)
may help you. You can use a plugin from `File>Setting>Plugin>Browse Repositories` and search for `RoboPOJOGenerator`.
To use this plugin you first need to create a separate package like "data", right-click the package and you will see Generate POJO from `JSON`. Also, you need to include `gson` library in `gradle` because this plugin will automatically generate annotation of `gson` like `@SerializedName`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this

This is the simple way

1. Right-click on the package name and select **New->Kotlin File/Class**
   [image]
2. Name the name (in my case, I am naming this as **Model**, you can name it whatever you like) and click **OK**.
   [image]
3. Paste this code, **this is your POJO/Model class**:

   ```
   class Model {
       var uid: String? = null
       var name: String? = null
   }
   ```

[image]

## How to use this

```
 val model = Model()
 model.name = "Sunil"
 Log.e("Model after", model.name)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA plugin:
JSON To Kotlin Class ​([JsonToKotlinClass](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-))​

Answer (score 0):

In my case Code -> Generate doesn't work, it is disabled (see screenshot)

[image]

You should install the plugin "JsonToKotlinClass"

[image: Install plugin for Android Studio]

Then right-click on the namespace and select

[image: Then right-click on the namespace and select]

Paste your JSON here. That's all, profit.

[image]

Answer (score -5):

```
data class VideoGame(val name: String, val publisher: String, var reviewScore: Int)
//Constructor 
val game: VideoGame = VideoGame("Gears of War", "Epic Games", 8)

print(game.name) // "Gears of War"
print(game.publisher) // "Epic Games"
print(game.reviewScore) // 8
game.reviewScore = 7
```