# Retrofit kotlin expected begin_object but was begin_array

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

**Main Activity**

```
   val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.78:3000")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val api = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)

    api.fetchLastNews().enqueue(object : Callback<List<News>>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<News>>, response: Response<List<News>>) {
            d("exemplo","onResponse")
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<News>>, t: Throwable) {
        d("exemplo","onFailure")
        }
    })
}
```

**Interface**

```
 interface ApiService {
@GET("/getultimas")
fun fetchLastNews(): Call<List<News>>
   }
```

**Data class**

```
 package com.example.navigationdrawer

data class News (
val titulo: String
   )
```

**Response from node api**

```
app.get('/getultimas', function (req, res) {
console.log("ultimas noticias");
results = transform(jsonLastNews);
res.json(results);
 });
```

Its giving error retrofit kotlin expected begin_object but was begin_array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array

Comment: What should i do with that?

Comment: Can you add response as well that you will get from that API.

Comment: I added the response edited

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: {
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "",
            "pubDate": "",
            "link": "",
            "guid": "",
            "author": "",
            "description": "",
            "content": "",
            "enclosure": {
                "link": "",
                "type": ""
            },
            "categories": [
                ""
            ]
        }
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GSON throwing "Expected BEGIN\_OBJECT but was BEGIN\_ARRAY"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array)

Comment: It's very confused, I can't understand I'm a beginner can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your data class News to related response from server,to convert json to pojo kotlin check this [Create POJO Class for Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180346/create-pojo-class-for-kotlin)

Edit:

because return json from server is `{ "items": [ { "title": "", "pubDate": "", "link": "", "guid": "", "author": "", "description": "", "content": "", "enclosure": { "link": "", "type": "" }, "categories": [ "" ] } ]}`
 
you can change you data class to

```
data class News {

    @SerializedName("items") //this json key
    @Expose
    val items: List<Item>?= null; /*items is list array because response [] tag*/

}
/* class for List Item */
data class Item {

    @SerializedName("title") //this key value from json
    @Expose
    val title:String; //this key value to variable string in kotlin the type is String

    @SerializedName("pubDate")
    @Expose
    val pubDate:String;

    @SerializedName("link")
    @Expose
    val link:String;
    /* you can add other data*/

}
```

Comment: I get this using the convert json2kotlin but what i should do with this? 
val json = getJson() // your json value here
val topic = Gson().fromJson(json, Json4Kotlin_Base::class.java)

Comment: You can get json to pojo from this link http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ 
then  Converted Kotlin Class to java using Code -> Convert Java File to Kotlin File or CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + K

Comment: i use that but still gives me the same error begin object but was begin array

Comment: Can u show me the return from server?for I'm try check the result for valid json format

Comment: { "items": [ { "title": "", "pubDate": "", "link": "", "guid": "", "author": "", "description": "", "content": "", "enclosure": { "link": "", "type": "" }, "categories": [ "" ] } }

Comment: after i'm check your json response not have close tag "]" for key items,please check at end of server response there should be a closing tag like `"categories": [ "" ] } ]  }`

Comment: Problem was resolved. The problem was that i was sending the item object and i just removed it from the endpoint and it was okay