# What should be the Kotlin class to represent a json with array of classes

Tags: kotlin, json-deserialization, kotlinx.serialization

Given the following JSON:

```
{
"from": 1,
"to": 3,
"results": [
    {
        "item": {
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "statusMessage": "",
            "requestId": "1"
        }
    },
    {
        "item": {
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "statusMessage": "",
            "requestId": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "item": {
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "statusMessage": "",
            "requestId": "3"
        }
    },
    {
        "item": {
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "statusMessage": "",
            "requestId": "4"
        }
    }
]}
```

What should be the correct Kotlin classes to define in order to de-serialize using `kotlinx.serialization.json.Json`?

I have tried:

```
data class Response (
  val from: Long,
  val to: Long,
  val results: List<Result>
)

data class Result (
  val item: List<Item>
)

data class Item (
  val status: String,
  val statusMessage: String,
  val requestID: String
)
```

My attempt does not describe the list of items correctly.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `item` should not be a list: `val item: Item`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of your `Result`s have exactly one `Item` with the key `"item"`, so it should be:

```
data class Result (
  val item: Item
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a class like below.

```
data class Temp(
    val from: Int, // 1
    val results: List<Result>,
    val to: Int // 3
) {
    data class Result(
        val item: Item
    ) {
        data class Item(
            val requestId: String, // 1
            val status: String, // SUCCESS
            val statusMessage: String
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine except the `Result` class. In JSON, arrays are kept between square brackets, like this: `[a, b, c]`. Notice that you have no square brackets in the `Result`.

Nevertheless, don't spend too much time with these kinds of problems. Use JSON to POJO converters instead.

https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo

Also, this StackOverflow link might be useful:

[Create POJO Class for Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180346/create-pojo-class-for-kotlin)